# Image won't load. I've used the jpg and i haven't made any typos

Tags: html

I've been trying to load an image from my hard drive, but it won't show. I honestly don't know what I'm doing as I'm new to HTML

Just started learning HTML

```
<img src="SPQR.img.jpg" alt="SPQR">
```

Comment: post your html code here

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your should try to do like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="image" with="100" height="100" src="#" alt="image name" />

<script>
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src",e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="location of file" alt="my image"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also make sure you have typed the correct image name as well as image format.